# Error in Java SOAP client using SAAJ

Tags: java, soap

My Java version is Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_37-b06).
My Maven dependency is for the javax.xml.messaging.URLEndpoint class is:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax</groupId>
    <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
    <version>6.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

My code is:

```
import javax.xml.soap.*;
...
SOAPConnectionFactory factory = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance();
SOAPConnection connection = factory.createConnection();
SOAPMessage message = createSOAPRequest();
String url = "http://localhost:8080/serviceapp/hello";
connection.call(message, url);
```

The stacktrace I get is:

```
java.lang.ClassFormatError: Absent Code attribute in method that is not native or abstract in class file javax/xml/messaging/URLEndpoint
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
    at
```

What is the cause of the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, the problem can be solved by updating the version of the Maven JAXB plugin:

```
<groupId>org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2</groupId>
<artifactId>maven-jaxb2-plugin</artifactId>
<version>0.11.0</version>
```

I also had to modify the Java EE version to:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javaee</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>5</version>
    </dependency>
```